# Handling Double Tap in Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

This question is too primitive, but I have been trying for the last 8 hours, and it is eating away my energy ( and confidence levels too :))

In my class, I have registered for Targeted touches.

```
  [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:-1 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

I would like to check if the user is performing single tap or double tap. In ccTouchBegan method, first gets a touch with singleTap, then gets a touch with doubleTap. I found a very interesting solution for this one, in one of the Cocos2d Forums. ( I could not locate it now.. )

The solution goes like this.

```
switch (touch.tapCount) {
            case 2:
                [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleSingleTouch:)  object:singleTouchLocation];
             // Handle Double Touch here
                break;
            case 1:


                self.singleTapLocation = ccp(location.x,location.y);
                self.singleTouchLocation = touch;

                [self performSelector:@selector(handleSingleTouch:) withObject:touch afterDelay:0.3
             ];



                break;
        }
```

Everything looks to be working fine. Essentially, you schedule a single touch handler with a delay and see if it is actually a double tap. If it is a double tap, then cancel singletap handler and perform logic for double tap.

But my problem is, In the single touch handler (handleSingleTouch), I am adding a CCSprite to the UI. This action is not working. No sprite gets added. (Although the method is called.). In fact this works, If I call the selector with no delay, but with delay, the sprite is not added.

I am not a Objective C expert, So, I apologize if the question is too primitive.

Edit 1: The original [thread](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6505).

Edit 2: Posting handleSingleTouch.. only relevant code.

```
-(void) handleSingleTouch:(UITouch * ) touch  {

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CGPoint glLocation = [MainSceneLayer locationFromTouch:touch];
    //Single tap
    CCLOG(@"Single tap: Adding marker image");


    if(zoomedOut) {

        CGPoint globalCoordinates = [quadConvertor convertLocalToGlobal:location 
                                                       inActiveQuadrant:activeQuadrant];



        if( [self isTouchValidForSelectedItem:globalCoordinates] == Matched) {
            [self addMarkerImages:glLocation];
        } else if([self isTouchValidForSelectedItem:globalCoordinates] == NotMatched) {
            [missedLabel stopAllActions];

            for (ImageQuadrants* quad in quadrants) { 
                if(quad.quadrantNumber == activeQuadrant) {

                    missedLabel.position  =  ccp((quad.center.x * -1)+glLocation.x  , (quad.center.y * -1)+glLocation.y);

                    //markers.position =  ccp((quad.center.x * -1)+touchPosition.x  , 320);


                }

            }


            id blinkAction = [CCBlink actionWithDuration:1 blinks:3];
            id makeInvible = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(makeInvisible:)];



            id seq = [CCSequence actions:blinkAction, makeInvible,  nil];

            [missedLabel runAction:seq];

        } else {

            [alreadyAccountedLabel stopAllActions];

            for (ImageQuadrants* quad in quadrants) { 
                if(quad.quadrantNumber == activeQuadrant) {

                    alreadyAccountedLabel.position  =  ccp((quad.center.x * -1)+glLocation.x  , (quad.center.y * -1)+glLocation.y);

                    //markers.position =  ccp((quad.center.x * -1)+touchPosition.x  , 320);


                }

            }


            id blinkAction = [CCBlink actionWithDuration:1 blinks:3];
            id makeInvible = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(makeInvisible1:)];



            id seq = [CCSequence actions:blinkAction, makeInvible,  nil];

            [alreadyAccountedLabel runAction:seq];


        }

    }


    swipeStartPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];


}
```

Comment: Can you post the handleSingleTouch: method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know if thats a typo in your question only but your delay method is all wrong. There is no `withDelay:` argument. it should look like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(handleSingleTouch:) withObject:touch afterDelay:0.1];
```

**EDIT**:

Since your problem is most probably with the touch getting lost. Try `[touch retain]` before calling the delayed method. Another way is changing the `handleSingleTouch:` method to take two floats x and y or a CCPoint as arguments instead of a UITouch. Then you create the floats before the delayed method and pass them in the delayed method. This way you will avoid a memory leak from retaining a touch as well since most probably you cant release it after calling the delayed method.

hope this helps

Comment: Have you tried to retain the touch before calling the delayed method? I havent seen where in your code the sprite gets added but if it depends on the value of the touch then maybe the touch is being released before the delayed method is called.

Comment: I think, you might be on to something. I never thought about that. Will try and let you know.

Comment: could you please add this as an answer. I will accept it. The problem is with the touch object, getting lost. I think it was retained, but it gets overwritten or something like that. I will investigate further. But since you pointed me to the right direction :), you get the credit.